# I installed Mongodb from homebrew and now when i enter mongo --version it shows command not found

Tags: mongodb, installation, mongodb-query

I have installed mongodb7.0 from their website community edition and from homebrew too.
now typing

mongo --version shows

`zsh: command not found: mongo`

and 'mongod --version' shows

zsh: killed     mongod --version

how should i install it on mac sonoma

Comment: " installed from their website and from homebrew too" I don't think that is very smart, you should install only one. `mongo` is the old legacy shell, which is not supported anymore and not part of the installation.